# iOS - MFMailComposerViewController cannot cancel if addAttachmentData:

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

My MFMailComposer code:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[mailViewController setDelegate:self];
[mailViewController setSubject:@"subject"];
[mailViewController setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"email@email.com"]];
[mailViewController setMessageBody:@"body" isHTML:NO];

for (int i = 0; i < self.imagesData.count; i++)
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSSS"];
    [mailViewController addAttachmentData:[self.imagesData objectAtIndex:i] mimeType:[self contentTypeForImageData:[self.imagesData objectAtIndex:i]] fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"portfolio_%@_%d", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]], i]];
}

[self presentViewController:mailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

With this code I'd press cancel and delete draft and nothing happens, the MFMailComposerViewController doesn't close.

I added the delegates already:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error{
if(error) NSLog(@"ERROR - mailComposeController: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

if (result == MFMailComposeResultSent)
{
    NSLog(@"It's away!");
}

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If you remove attachments, is it working fine?

Comment: Does the delegate get called? Is there an error?

Answer (score 1):

OK I found an answer. I was stupid.

I used `setDelegate` instead of `setMailComposeDelegate`

Comment: That's an easy mistake to make since there are the two different delegate properties.